# How can I use Google Map's distance matrix API in flutter. Can anyone help me

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-places-api, google-distancematrix-api

I am making my final year project and I am stuck in distance matrix. I am making an app in which I am using google maps, but I don't know how to find the time and distance between two places. I read some articles but can't understand I am beginner of flutter.

Answer (score 3):

First you need a Google Maps API key, and to get that you need a Google cloud account, it's free to create one, and you get a free trial as well, which should enough for a study project.
This link may be helpful for setting up an account and a project : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/cloud-setup

After account and project setup you need to [enable the distance matrix API](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/distance-matrix-backend.googleapis.com)

Then [create an API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/get-api-key#creating-api-keys)

Once you have your API key, you are ready to start using the API: All you need to make an API call is your API key and the origin and destination locations (for that you can use latitude/longitude, full address, place IDs...). Here is an example using latitude, longitude coordinates:

```json
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?destinations=40.659569,-73.933783&origins=40.6655101,-73.89188969999998&key=**YOUR_API_KEY_HERE**
```

You can provide many locations separated by a pipe(|) for both the origin and the destination(e.g:`11.45455,-13.4675434|12.353645,-32.463634|11.45455,-13.4675434`...), the API will match each single origin location to all the destinations and return distance for each pair (basically one request will return origins times destinations results).

NOTE: the example I provided is very simple, but the distance matrix has more feature (e.g: taking into account traffic) visit this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/overview) for an overview of the features of the API.

**Flutter**

To call the API in a flutter app, you will need an HTTP client such as [DIO](https://pub.dev/packages/dio):

```dart
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
void getDistanceMatrix() async {
  try {
    var response = await Dio().get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?destinations=40.659569,-73.933783&origins=40.6655101,-73.89188969999998&key=YOUR_API_KEY_HERE');
    print(response);
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}
```

To see what type of response you will get visit this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/overview#distance-matrix-responses).

*The content of all the links in this answer may change in the future*

Answer (score 2):

```dart
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

Dio _dio = new Dio(); 

Response response = await _dio.get(
        "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?destinations=$dlatitude,$dlongitude&origins=$slatitude,$slongitude&key=YOUR_KEY_HERE");
    print(response.data);
```

Note:
the slatitude,dlatitude, slongitude and dlongitude is the dynamic value.

you can also update them as:

```
String dlatitude = destinationLocation!.latitude.toString();
String dlongitude = destinationLocation!.longitude.toString();
String slatitude = startLocation.latitude.toString();
String slongitude = startLocation.longitude.toString();
```

Hope this helps you. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the url you used to call the api just pass Your Google Api Key and start end latitude and longitude value.

> 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?destinations=40.659569,-73.933783&origins=40.6655101,-73.89188969999998&key=YOUR_API_KEY_HERE'

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

static Future<dynamic> getDistance({double startLatitude, double startLongitude, double endLatitude, double endLongitude}) async {
  String Url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?destinations=${startLatitude},${startLongitude}&origins=${endLatitude},${endLongitude}&key=YOUR_API_KEY-HERE';
  try {
    var response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse(Url),);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return jsonDecode(response.body);
    } else
      return null;
  }
  catch (e) {
    print(e);
    return null;
  }
}
```

Call the function

```
getDistance(
  startLatitude: '52.2165157',
  startLongitude: '6.9437819',
  endLatitude: '52.3546274',
  endLongitude: '4.8285838'
);
```

Answer (score -1):

you can find the distance by the HaverSine formula, implemented in dart as:

```
import'dart:math' as Math;
void main()=>print(getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(73.4545,73.4545,83.5454,83.5454));



double getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2) {
  var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
  var dLat = deg2rad(lat2-lat1);  // deg2rad below
  var dLon = deg2rad(lon2-lon1); 
  var a = 
    Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
    Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * 
    Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2)
    ; 
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
  var d = R * c; // Distance in km
  return d;
}

double deg2rad(deg) {
  return deg * (Math.pi/180);
}
```

> ```
> Output:
> 1139.9231530436646
> ```

Source [Calculate distance between two latitude-longitude points? (Haversine formula)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points-haversine-formulaand) credits to Chuck and @cmd_prompter.

**Option 2**

You can use https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator plugin if you are looking for the shortest distance between two locations aka LatLng.

> ```
> double distanceInMeters = 
>   await Geolocator().distanceBetween(52.2165157, 6.9437819, 52.3546274, 4.8285838);
> ```